# QBuffer from void pointer and memory size

Tags: c++, qt, void-pointers, qbytearray, qbuffer

I'm looking for the most simple and or elegant way to create a QBuffer in C++ Qt5.6 from `void * data` and `long data_size`.

I tried casting the void to a char pointer and using the `QByteArray::fromRawData()` as well as using `QDataStream` to fill a `QByteArray`. In both cases I didn't succeed.

Comment: What does "I didn't succeed" mean? Did you get an error or something?

Comment: I'm using the QBuffer to play audio and in every case so far I get only noise or silence. When casting to a char pointer I get a buffer underrun somewhere in the process.

Comment: Do you know, what QByteArray::fromRawData did not copy buffer to QByteArray? With this method QByteArray uses your pointer.

Comment: @gro - this question is about QBuffer from a void *. If you have a different question, you should post it as such.

Answer (score 4):

`QByteArray::QByteArray(const char *data, int size)` will copy the data.

`QByteArray::fromRawData(const char *data, int size)` will use the already existing data.

Depending on your implementation, not copying the data might end up being problematic.

After you have the data in a byte array, there are several ways to go, you can directly construct a buffer:

```
QBuffer(QByteArray *byteArray, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
```

or more likely, since you are playing audio, you might want to reusing the same buffer and use one of the following to refill it:

```
setBuffer(QByteArray *byteArray)
setData(const QByteArray &data)
```

Lastly, there is also `void QBuffer::setData(const char *data, int size)` for which you don't even need the byte array step at all.

Lastly, remember that `QBuffer` is an IO device - it needs to be opened in order for it to work. A quick test shows that it works as expected:

```
char data[] = {1, 2, 3};
void * vdata = data;
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.setData((char *)vdata, sizeof(data));
buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qDebug() << buffer.readAll(); // outputs "\x01\x02\x03"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for an elegant way to create a QBuffer from data and data_size, I would simply use this:

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.setData(static_cast<const char*>(data), data_size);
```

Note: this *copies* the memory pointed to by `data`.

---

I have no idea why you are unable to succeed, maybe you forgot to add the `data_size` as size argument for `QByteArray::fromRawData`? In that case `strlen(data)` would be used to calculate the size.

And if you are using something like this:

```
QByteArray byteArray = QByteArray::fromRawData(static_cast<const char*>(data), data_size);
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
```

Then the `byteArray` must remain valid until the QBuffer is destroyed. And since `QByteArray::fromRawData(...)` does not copy, the memory pointed to by `data` must remain valid as well. Failing to meet that requirement would also explain any failure.